# What's the best way to prevent my Mac from updating macOS?

Tags: macos, software-update

I'd like to keep my Mac on Catalina forever. Other than disabling "Automatically keep my Mac up to date", is there anything else I can do to prevent my Mac from upgrading to newer macOS versions? I'm still interested in receiving Catalina updates and Safari updates, but they don't need to be automatic.

This machine will be kept online, but only used for audio software. It doesn't need to be secure.

Comment: "This machine will be kept online, but only used for audio software. It doesn't need to be secure." – I would urge you to reconsider that stance. Being a good Internet netizen means caring about the community as a whole. Insecure computers not only put the owner at risk, they are also used to attack others. In fact, the overwhelming majority of attacks is launched from insecure computers that were taken over, also the overwhelming majority of spam and phishing mails is sent from insecure computers connected to the Internet. Famously, one DDoS attack on Stack Exchange was launched by a network

Comment: … of security cameras that were not properly secured.

Comment: As professional hacker, I can **highly recommend** you to not update to the latest version of your OS, including security updates. This makes my job of breaking into your computer *much easier*!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually that is pretty easy to do.

I've got a 16" MBP on which I do *not* want to upgrade to Big Sur (at least yet) and here is what I have done.

First go to `System Preferences > Software update` and uncheck "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" like this:

[image: Software Update]

Then click the "Advanced..." button and un check everything except the first option, like this:

[image: Software Update 2]

Note that is is OK to leave the last option "Install System data files and security updates." But being the mildly paranoid techie I choose to leave that off. Your call tho.

Note that there is really no way to hide the Big Sur "Upgrade Now" button but when there are updates for your current macOS version they will appear below that under a very small "more..." link. That will **NOT** install Big Sur. Instead it will install just the updates to your current version of macOS.

Comment: I would strongly recommend **not** disabling 'Install system data files and security updates' option, as that disables updates to security data files. You can leave 'Download new updates when available' enabled if you like, while that will likely *download* Big Sur (as well as any Catalina updates), it won't install them. 'Install app updates from the App Store' doesn't affect system updates, only apps from the App Store, so that can be left either enabled or disabled. 'Install macOS updates' is the only one that would cause macOS to automatically install updates. Note that even with that disa

Comment: "But being the mildly paranoid techie I choose to leave [security updates] off." - **What?!**

Comment: Thank you for answering the question as asked.